# The fundamental group of $U(n)/O(n)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Since $O(n)$ is a subgroup of $U(n)$, we can consider the quotient space $L_n=U(n)/O(n)$. The quotient space is homotopic to the ($n$-th) Lagrangian Grassmannian, and it is known that its fundamental group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$.

This fact is an easy consequence of homotopy long exact sequence. Namely we have an exact sequence
$$\dots \to \pi_1(O(n)) \to \pi_1(U(n)) \to \pi_1(L_n) \to 1.$$
Now $\pi_1(O(n)) = \mathbb Z_2$ ($n\geq 3$) and $\pi_1(U(n))=\mathbb Z$, therefore $\pi_1(L_n)=\mathbb Z$ if $n \geq 3$.

But, since $\pi_1(O(2))=\mathbb Z$, we need to see that **the map $\pi_1(O(2)) \to \pi_1(U(2))$ is the zero map.**

Now, 
$$t \mapsto \pmatrix{\cos 2\pi t & -\sin 2\pi t \\ \sin 2\pi t & \cos 2\pi t}$$
gives the generator of $\pi_1(O(2))$.

**Can we construct an explicit homotopy from the above loop to the constant loop in $U(2)$?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can easily write down such a homotopy: let $\theta(t)$ be the matrix $$\theta(t)=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(2\pi t) & -\sin(2\pi t)\\\sin(2\pi t) & \cos(2\pi t)\end{pmatrix}.$$

For any $t\in \mathbb R$, the matrix $\theta(t)$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $e^{\pm 2i\pi t}$ and the change of basis matrix doesn't depend on $t$.

More precisely, let $P$ be the matrix $$P=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}i&1\\1&i\end{pmatrix}$$
then $$\forall t\in\mathbb R, \qquad \theta(t)=P\begin{pmatrix}e^{2i\pi t} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-2i\pi t}\end{pmatrix}P^{-1}.$$
Furthermore, you can check that $P$ and $\begin{pmatrix}e^{2i\pi t} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-2i\pi t}\end{pmatrix}$ are both unitary.

This allows us to define the following map : $$\begin{array}{rccc} H: & [0,1]\times [0,1] & \longrightarrow & U(2) \\ & (t,s) & \longmapsto & P\begin{pmatrix}e^{2i\pi st} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-2i\pi st}\end{pmatrix}P^{-1}\end{array}$$
$H$ takes value in $U(2)$, is continuous and $H(\cdot,0)$ is the constant loop while $H(\cdot,1)$ is your loop.

**Edit**: Actually, this homotopy is just a homotopy of maps and not of loops.

In fact, this is the best that one can expect because $\pi_1(O(2),I_2)\rightarrow \pi_1(U(2),I_2)$ is a group isomorphism. So you won't get any other information about $\pi_1(L_2)$ in this way and your loop can't be homotopic (as loops) to a constant loop in $U(2)$.

However there is a different, but more general, way to compute $\pi_1(L_n)$: consider the following map  $$\begin{array}{cccl} & U(n)& \rightarrow & S^1 \\ & M & \mapsto & {\det}^2(M) \end{array}$$
This map induces a continuous map $f:L_n\rightarrow S^1$ which is a fibration with fibre $SU(n)/SO(n)$. So one can use the long exact sequence in homotopy groups : $$\cdots \rightarrow \pi_1(SU(n)/SO(n)) \rightarrow \pi_1(L_n) \rightarrow \pi_1(S^1) \rightarrow \pi_0(SU(n)/SO(n)) \rightarrow \cdots $$

But,

1. $SO(n)$ is path-connected,
2. $SU(n)$ path-connected and simply-connected,
3. we have the fibration : $SO(n)\rightarrow SU(n) \rightarrow SU(n)/SO(n)$
   thus $$\pi_1(SU(n)/SO(n))=1.$$

Hence $$\pi_0(SU(n)/SO(n))=1 \qquad \text{ and } \qquad \pi_1(SU(n)/SO(n))=1.$$
and consequently the map $$\pi_1(L_n)\rightarrow \pi_1(S^1)$$ is a group isomorphism which gives you the result.

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is $H(\cdot,s)$ does not seem to be a loop. Namely we have to require $H$ to satisfy $H(0,s)=H(1,s)$ for all $s$, so that $H$ descends to a map $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z \times [0,1] \to U(2)$.

Comment: Yes, that's true and we can't ask $H$ to satisfy such a condition. The morphism you are looking for is not the zero map but an isomorphism. See the update of my answer. By the way how did you get your long exact sequence ? At the end, you should have $\pi_0(O(2))$ which is has two elements.

Comment: You are right. $\pi_0(O(2))$ should be $\mathbb Z_2$.

Comment: Ok. However, you should be careful of the notation $\mathbb Z_2$ that suggests that $\pi_0$ is a group, which is wrong in general. The end of the long exact sequence is not actually an exact sequence of groups, but of sets with maps and not group morphisms.